# How to read a sqlite3 database, using node js, synchronously?

Tags: json, node.js, sqlite

```
exports.allProbes = function() {
    var rows = db.all("SELECT * FROM probes;");
    return rows;
};
```

---

```
main:
var json_values = allProbes();
```

Is it possible to do something like that? 
I mean, without using a callback function: just, read data (sync mode) from the db. and return a json formatted output?

Thanks.

Comment: What module are you using? It all depends on if it has synchronous support.

Comment: i've installed sqlite3 with the following command: "npm install sqlite3"

Comment: I need the same as you OP. I need guarantee that my queries are executed in order. Wrapping it in promises is a PITAS

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will not be able to do that with sqlite3. With sqlite3 module the only available mode of operation is asynchronous execution, and you will have to use a callback. Eg.

```
exports.allProbes = function(callback) {
    db.all("SELECT * FROM probes;", function(err, all) {
        callback(err, all);  
    });
};
```

Then in your code:

```
var json_values;

allProbes(function(err, all) {
    json_values = all;
});
```

Check [sqlite3 API Docs](https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3/wiki/API).

Comment: or just.. `db.all("SELECT * FROM probes;", callback)`,

Comment: Can't we use a promise?

Answer (score 42):

There are a few npm packages such as [better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3) and [sqlite-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite-sync) that allow for synchronous SQLite queries. Here's an example:

```
var sqlite = require("better-sqlite3");
var db = new sqlite("example.db");

var rows = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM probes").all();
console.log(rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make an asynchronous function using async/await

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

You have to install sql.js with npm install --save sql.js

Rest follow the below steps :

```
var fs = require('fs');    
var sql = require('sql.js');    
var bfr = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/db.sqlite');

var db = new sql.Database(bfr);
db.each('SELECT * FROM test', function (row) {

  console.log(row);

});
```

More details you can get on the below this link : https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-access-a-local-db-on-windows-through-electron/22400/13

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The _file_ is read synchronously, but the database query still requires an async callback.